# Unable to delete document in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am not able to delete document in MongoDB using PHP

Here are my codes:

```
<?php
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2011-01-30 00:00:00"));

// connect
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->selectdb("testdb");
$collections = $db->listCollections();


foreach ($collections as $collection) {
echo $collection."<br />";

$cursor = $collection->find(array('created_at'=>array('$lte' => $end)));
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {

//db.orders.deleteMany( { "client" : "Crude Traders Inc." } );
$did =  $doc['_id'];

echo $did;
echo '<br>';
echo $doc['name'];
echo $collection;
$ret = $collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($did)), true);


}}

?>
```

I m able to fetch the list, but unable to delete a single row. I did not find appropriate over net or i am doing some silly mistake.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Shashank This is a _Read The Manual_ type question.  Always, always do your research and make some coding attempts before you post a question.  This way, no one else has to waste time telling you to read the manual.  Here is the manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/  Please delete this question, as it will not be helpful to future SO readers.